# Finding max period of 8-bit LFSR

Tags: stream-cipher, lfsr

I am a bit stuck there and trying to figure out the approach for given problem.

What is the maximim period of a pseudo-random sequence generated by the
8-bit LFSR with connection polynomial C(X) = 1+X^2 +X^4 +X^5 +X^6 +X^7 +X^8?

Any help would be highly apreciated...

Comment: seems like this is not a primitive polynomial so how can I figure out what the max period could be?

Answer (score 1):

If a connection polynomial of degree $d$ is primitive, i.e., it is irreducible and has a root of order $2^d-1,$ then the period is $2^d-1,$ for any nonzero loading.

There is more information in [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12831/maximal-length-lfsr-with-n-bits-when-the-factorization-of-2n-1-is-unavailab)